# Pass Server.R session variable into global.R in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

I am extracting url_search query using

```
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search). #in Server.R
```

I need to pass query variable from server.R to global.R

```
hdfs_path <- MyQuery#in global.R
```

I am not able to make 'query' as a global variable so that it is read in Global.R.
Is there way to pass the query variable to Global.R?

I tried this solution, but did not work for me:

```
MyQuery <- reactiveValues() #in Global.R 

assign('MyQuery',query,envir=.GlobalEnv) #assign from server.R to global.R
```

Please help as I am not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: Should your `assign` code be `assign('MyQuery',  MyQuery, envir=.GlobalEnv)` ?

Comment: Sorry, that was typo. I did use it as assign('MyQuery', MyQuery, envir=.GlobalEnv), but did not work.

Comment: @Pork Chop: Thanks for you reply. I have tried using it, but did not work.

Comment: I recall that `jdharrison` had an example, you can look at it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749749/shiny-ui-save-the-changes-in-the-inputs

Comment: Also, why not save that query string as a variable in the database table?

Comment: @manzoorRazaak Perhaps you want to update your post if it was a typo.