# select row in a shiny data table via URL GET method

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Has anyone seen a code snipped or something in the documentation to select a row in a data table of shiny app by submitting some get parameters?

Something like `http://mywebsite.com/shinyapp/?row=1&row=2`

Or if somebody could point me to some ideas how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After browsing stack overflow a little, I found a simple example [How do you pass parameters to a shiny app via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872222/how-do-you-pass-parameters-to-a-shiny-app-via-url) and adapted it to my needs.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)


ui <- bootstrapPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  textInput("text", "Text", ""),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    print(query)
    if (!is.null(query[['text']])) {
      text_string <- query[['text']]
      DT::selectRows(mytable_proxy, as.numeric(text_string))
      updateTextInput(session, "text", value = text_string)
    }
  })

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({mtcars})
  mytable_proxy = DT::dataTableProxy('mytable')
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So by executing the app and open it in a browser, I can add the GET parameter and I have the number in the text field and the row get selected. http://127.0.0.1:3010/?text=4 (the IP and Port might be different in your case).