# RShiny Output as HTML or PDF

Tags: html, shiny, pdf-generation

Originally, I built a shiny application that served as a dashboard for clients. However, my team later determined that, rather than having a live dashboard that clients can log into, we would simply send pdf reports. I have been trying to determine if there is a way to convert a shiny page into a static html file (or even better, directly as a pdf) in a fast and convenient programmatic way as there are hundreds of pages that need to be saved (one for each client).

Comment: A clean solution would be to build a RMarkdown using customer as a rendering parameter

Comment: The issue is that we want to keep all the UI exactly as is displayed in the app. From Googling, this didn't seem possible.

Comment: A less clean solution would be to use `{webshot}` to get a png (and use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872222/how-do-you-pass-parameters-to-a-shiny-app-via-url) to pass parameter via URL)

Comment: RMarkdown, makes pretty dashboards with `{flexdashboard}`