# Update data and parameter of a deployed shiny app via initial shiny app in which the deployed is displayed as url

Tags: r, shiny, pins

I have the `shiny` app below in which when the user uploads an excel file then a `selectInput()` with its column names is displayed and also a url that leads to a deployed `shiny` app.

This deployed `shiny` app is now deployed with `data<-iris` and `y<-Petal.Length` but what I want to do is to pass to it the uploaded file as `data` and the selected column name as `y`. Then it will work (no problem with this)

How can I achieve it? I know that maybe one option would with an API and another with the `pins` package but Im not sure how to do it. Of course Im open to alternative solution.

**initial app**

```
# Install and load necessary packages
library(shiny)
library(pins)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Link"),
  column(3, fileInput("file1", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls"))),
  uiOutput("select"),
  uiOutput("tab"),

)

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  url <- a("Shinyapp", href="https://deniz4shinyml.shinyapps.io/iris/")
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    tagList("URL link:", url)
  })
  
  file_info <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
           "xlsx" = readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath)

  })
  
  #####pins######
  board_rsc <- pins::board_connect()
  board_rsc %>% pin_write(file_info())
  ######pins#####
  
  output$select<-renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    selectInput("sel","select one column",choices = unique(colnames(file_info())),
                selected = unique(colnames(file_info()))[1],
                multiple = F)
  })
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**deployed app**

```
# Load required libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(pins)

# Load Iris dataset
data<-iris
y<-"Petal.Length"

######pin section
#data<-pin_read(board_rsc)
#y=?
########

# Define the UI for the Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Sepal Scatterplot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server logic for the Shiny app
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = data[[y]])) +
      geom_point() 
  })
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In this app use pins package to pin (pin_write) the user loaded data to Posit board.  In the deployed app, you use pin_read to read the pinned data.  Initially, you can pin iris data to the posit board (in a separate R code), and deploy the app.

Comment: By Posit board, I meant `pins::board_connect()`.

Comment: You can pass parameters to a Shiny app with the url - see <https://stackoverflow.com/q/32872222/1100107>. However that could not been possible if the dataset is big, because there is a limit for the url length.

Comment: @YBS I modified using both the initial and deployed app (just for the case) in order to understand the process of using pins maybe if you can provide an example answer.Dont care that I will be uploading different data every time. I want the logic

Comment: also @StéphaneLaurent could you provide as example answer based on the modified question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate my comment, using parameters, your initial app would look like:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Link"),
  fileInput("file1", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls")),
  uiOutput("select"),
  uiOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    jsonData <- jsonlite::toJSON(Data())
    parameters <- 
      paste0("data=", URLencode(jsonData), "&y=", URLencode(input$sel))
    url <- paste0("https://deniz4shinyml.shinyapps.io/iris/?", parameters)
    tags$a("Shinyapp", href = url)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$sel)
  
  Data <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    path <- input$file1$datapath
    ext <- tools::file_ext(path)
    switch(
      ext,
      xlsx = readxl::read_xlsx(path),
      xls  = readxl::read_xls(path),
      csv  = read.csv(path)
    )
  })
  
  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "sel", "select one column", choices = colnames(Data()),
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  }) |> bindEvent(Data())
}
```

And the deployed app would look like:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Sepal Scatterplot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Data <- reactiveVal()
  y <- reactiveVal()
  
  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    Data(jsonlite::fromJSON(query$data))
    y(query$y)
  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(Data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = .data[[y()]])) +
      geom_point() 
  }) |> bindEvent(Data(), y())
}
```

But as I said, if the dataset is large, this would generate a long url which is not acceptable in some browsers. One way to reduce is to send only the selected column.

Or, instead of using a URL parameter for the data, upload the data to a Gist with the [gistr package](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/gistr/), put the Gist identifiant in a URL parameter, and in the deployed app, use **gistr** to get the data from this Gist.

---

## Edit: using JSON blob

If you don't have a Github account, you can use the [JSON blob website](https://jsonblob.com/) to store the data and retrieve it in the deployed app. Below I show how to do so by using the **httr2** package to perform the HTTP requests.

Initial app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(httr2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Link"),
  fileInput("file1", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls")),
  uiOutput("select"),
  uiOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    dataToSend <- list(data = Data(), y = input$sel)
    # send the data to jsonBlob
    req <- request("https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob")
    post <- req |>
      req_body_json(dataToSend) |> 
      req_perform()
    # get the url of the posted data
    blobURL <- resp_header(post, "location")
    #
    parameters <- paste0("url=", URLencode(blobURL))
    url <- paste0("https://deniz4shinyml.shinyapps.io/iris/?", parameters)
    tags$a("Shinyapp", href = url)
  }) |> bindEvent(input$sel)
  
  Data <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    path <- input$file1$datapath
    ext <- tools::file_ext(path)
    switch(
      ext,
      xlsx = readxl::read_xlsx(path),
      xls  = readxl::read_xls(path),
      csv  = read.csv(path)
    )
  })
  
  output$select <- renderUI({
    selectInput(
      "sel", "select one column", choices = colnames(Data()),
      multiple = FALSE
    )
  }) |> bindEvent(Data())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Deployed app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(httr2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Sepal Scatterplot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Data <- reactiveVal()
  y <- reactiveVal()
  
  observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    url <- query$url
    if(!is.null(url)) {
      # get the contents of the blob at this url
      List <- request(url) |> req_perform() |> resp_body_json()
      Data(List$data)
      y(List$y)
    } else {
      print("hmm.. strange!")
    }
  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(Data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = .data[[y()]])) +
      geom_point() 
  }) |> bindEvent(Data(), y())
}
```

Comment: the deployed app does not run in order then to be deployed as it returns:   Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7470
Warning: Error in : Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
  50: base::stop
  49: stop
  48: jsonlite::fromJSON
  45: observe [C:\Users\User\Documents\iris/app.R#20]
  44: <observer>
   1: shiny::runApp
Warning: Error in geom_point: Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'Sepal.Length' not found   maybe the gistr solution is better to be elaborated?

Comment: @firmo23 Very strange, I've just done some checks and it worked fine. Are you sure the file you upload is correct? Also could you try to replace `Data(jsonlite::fromJSON(query$data))` with `if(!is.null(query$data)) Data(jsonlite::fromJSON(query$data))`.

Comment: the deployed app now works but without the initial plot I get the same error and this is from my logs in shinyapps.io 2024-02-14T16:33:09.401512+00:00 shinyapps[11223587]: Warning: Error in geom_point: Problem while computing aesthetics.
2024-02-14T16:33:09.406360+00:00 shinyapps[11223587]: ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
2024-02-14T16:33:09.411184+00:00 shinyapps[11223587]: Caused by error:
2024-02-14T16:33:09.416225+00:00 shinyapps[11223587]: ! object 'Sepal.Length' not found

Comment: the libraries are missing and also shinyApp(ui, server)
is missing at the end but ok I added those but I still have the same error when i launch it and also after trying to send to it the data from the local app

Comment: @firmo23 Are you sure the data you upload has a `Sepal.Length` column? Please double-check. Also, I edited my answer to add another solution.

Comment: yes I upload an iris .csv from the initial,,but before that the deployed app when runs for 1st time in the secondary solution as well displays nothing and also cannot find the Sepal.Length which seems logical as initially you pass it empty reactiveVal() Data

Comment: the deployed app shpuld already exists with some initial data (iris) and Petal.Length selected

Comment: @firmo23 `Data()` is initially `NULL` but the `renderPlot` is followed by `|> bindEvent(Data(), y())`, so this `renderPlot` is not executed when `Data()` is `NULL`. Please double check your file **iris.csv**. That should work. Also try `read.csv("iris.csv")` in the console and check the column names.

Comment: @firmo23 *"the deployed app shpuld already exists with some initial data (iris) and Petal.Length selected"* -> If you want this behavior, initialize the reactive values: `Data(iris)` and `Data("Petal.Length")`.

Comment: ok now the deployed app is working with Data <- reactiveVal(iris)
  y <- reactiveVal("Petal.Length")
  but when I use the local to pass it the new csv(iris again) but with another y, the deployed opens but with an error Warning: Error in fortify: `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by `fortify()`,
 not a list.

Comment: @firmo23 I see! You have to replace `List <- request(url) |> req_perform() |> resp_body_json()` with `List <- request(url) |> req_perform() |> resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your deployed app such that

1. It accepts `POST` requests.
2. In this `POST` request you receive your data and your column name and store it in a global variable.
3. You send a redirection status to tell the original app that it should redirect to the "normal" landing page.
4. In your server function, you assign a session specific name to the global variable in order to deal with concurrent requests (otherwise all users would see the same data as we use a *global* variable.

Below a POC.

#### Deployed App

```r
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)
library(jsonlite)

params <- list()

ui <- function(req) {
  if (identical(req$REQUEST_METHOD, "GET")) {
    ## Handle the "normal" app
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(width = 8L,
               tableOutput("table")
        ),
        column(width = 2L,
               tags$p("Passed column name:",
                      textOutput("column", inline = TRUE)))
      )
    )
  } else if (identical(req$REQUEST_METHOD, "POST")) {
    # Handle the POST
    body <- rawToChar(req$rook.input$read(-1))
    ## store the parameters
    params <<- c(params, latest = list(fromJSON(body)))
    httpResponse(
      status = 303L,
      headers = list(Location = paste0("http://", req$HTTP_HOST))
    )
  }
}
attr(ui, "http_methods_supported") <- c("GET", "POST")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ### store params with unique id to allow for a per session copy of data
  params[[session$token]] <- params$latest
  params$latest <<- NULL
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    shiny::validate(
      need(!is.null(params[[session$token]]$data), 
           "No data provided, app should be kicked off with a POST")
    )
    params[[session$token]]$data
  })
  
  output$column <- renderText({
    shiny::validate(
      need(!is.null(params[[session$token]]$column),
           "No column name provided, app should be kicked off with a POST")
    )
    params[[session$token]]$column
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Local App

```r
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

jscode <- HTML("
Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('redirect', function(message) {
  window.location = message.location;
});")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(jscode)), 
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4L, 
           selectInput("dataset", "Select Data Source", c("mtcars", "iris"))
    ),
    column(width = 4L, 
           selectInput("column", "Select Column", names(mtcars))
    ), 
    column(width = 4L, style = "margin-top: 25px;",
           actionButton("send", "Send Data")
    )
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    get(req(input$dataset))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "column", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  
  observe({
    deployed_app_url <- "http://127.0.0.1:7770" 
    rq <- POST(deployed_app_url,
               config(followlocation = 0),
               body = list(data = my_data(),
                           column = input$column),
               encode = "json")
    session$sendCustomMessage("redirect", 
                              list(location = rq$headers$location))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$send)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Live

[image: Gif showing the flow between teh 2 apps]

---

#### Update

If you do not want to move from the local app to the deployed app, simply change your local app slightly:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(jscode)), 
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 4L, 
           selectInput("dataset", "Select Data Source", c("mtcars", "iris"))
    ),
    column(width = 4L, 
           selectInput("column", "Select Column", names(mtcars))
    ), 
    column(width = 4L, style = "margin-top: 25px;",
           actionButton("send", "Send Data")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12L,
           uiOutput("lnk"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    get(req(input$dataset))
  })
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "column", choices = names(my_data()))
  })
  
  output$lnk <- renderUI({
    deployed_app_url <- "http://127.0.0.1:7770" 
    rq <- POST(deployed_app_url,
               config(followlocation = 0),
               body = list(data = my_data(),
                           column = input$column),
               encode = "json")
    tags$a(href = rq$headers$location, "Deployed App", target = "_blank")
    # session$sendCustomMessage("redirect", 
    #                           list(location = ))
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$send)
    
}
```

*N.B.* The `renderUI` is an overkill, as the link to the deployed app won't change anyways. However, this workflow makes sure that we send the data at least once before proceeding, so making the link conditional on an inital POST makes sense to me.

Comment: might work but first of all the local app breaks down after sending the data and it should not  as it includes the url that  should be clicked and redirect us to the deployed app and also in case we will need to load other datataset

Comment: well, the redirect is just a gimmick, remove the `sendCustomMessage` and add a link. That's not a dealbreaker. Tricky part was how to pass data from local to deployed and the `POST` method circumvents issue3s with too long data as with the `GET`  method.

Answer (score 1):

While the above answers look fine, I will give another answer using `pins` package.

First pin a dataset to be used by deployed app.

```
library(pins)

os <- Sys.info()[['sysname']]

if (os == "Windows"){       ####### local laptop folder for initial set-up
  my_psr_board <- board_folder("C:/Users/yourpath")
} else if (os == "Linux"){  ##############     for publishing on Posit WorkBench
  ## connect to Posit Connect
  my_psr_board <- pins::board_connect()
}

df_pinned <- mtcars
pins::pin_write(my_psr_board, x = df_pinned, name = "df_pinned", type="rds")
```

Then you deploy your app which uses this pinned dataset named `df_pinned`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(pins)
library(dplyr)

# Define the UI for the Shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Iris Sepal Scatterplot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( uiOutput("xy")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot")
    )
  )
)

os <- Sys.info()[['sysname']]

if (os == "Windows"){       ####### local laptop folder for initial set-up
  user = ""
  my_psr_board <- board_folder("C:/Users/yourpath")
} else if (os == "Linux"){  ##############     for publishing on Posit WorkBench
  user = "<userID>/"  ### replace userID with your actual user ID
  ## connect to Posit Connect
  my_psr_board <- pins::board_connect()
}

# Define the server logic for the Shiny app
server <- function(input, output) {
  data_pinned <- reactive({
    dataset <- "df_pinned"
    pin_read(my_psr_board,paste0(user,dataset))
  })
  
  output$xy <- renderUI({
    req(data_pinned())
    tagList(
      selectInput("xvar", "Choose variable for x-axis", choices = names(data_pinned())),
      selectInput("yvar", "Choose variable for y-axis", choices = names(data_pinned()), selected = names(data_pinned())[2])
    )
  })
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(data_pinned(),input$xvar,input$yvar)
    df <- data_pinned() %>% dplyr::select(input$xvar,input$yvar)
    df
  })
  
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    req(data(),input$xvar,input$yvar)
    ggplot(data(), aes(x = .data[[input$xvar]], y = .data[[input$yvar]])) +
      geom_point() 
  })
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Next set-up your initial app that allows user to select the csv file to be pinned.

```
# Install and load necessary packages
library(shiny)
library(pins)
library(readxl)

# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny App with Link"),
  column(3, fileInput("file1", "Upload File", multiple = FALSE, accept = c(".csv"))),
  # uiOutput("select"),
  uiOutput("tab"),

)

os <- Sys.info()[['sysname']]

if (os == "Windows"){       ####### local laptop folder for initial set-up
  
  my_psr_board <- board_folder("C:/Users/yourpath")
} else if (os == "Linux"){  ##############     for publishing on Posit WorkBench
  
  ## connect to Posit Connect
  my_psr_board <- pins::board_connect()
}

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  url <- a("Shinyapp", href="https://deniz4shinyml.shinyapps.io/iris/")
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    tagList("URL link:", url)
  })

  file_info <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    newdf = read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
    newdf
  })

  observeEvent(file_info(), {
    df_pinned <- file_info()
    pins::pin_write(my_psr_board, x = df_pinned, name = "df_pinned", type="rds")
  })

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please note that in this set-up I am selecting x and y variables in the deployed app.  You can change it to the initial app.  Also, you can easily modify to select other files other than csv.  Also, you need to include the correct URL of the deployed app.